# Why does console.log(undefined) works sometimes but not others?

Tags: javascript, undefined

### Consider this code:

```
function x(){
    console.log(y);
}
x();
var t = x();
console.log(t);
```

This will throw an error. But if you comment the first console.log inside the function, it will work and print `undefined`.

What is the explanation of this behavior.

Thank you.

Comment: the console.log inside function x  tries to print out something not existing, but the console.log(t) prints out the functions return, which is undefined (not return)

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tpLtyofe/

Comment: You need to read a little bit about javascript variables, functions and scopes :)

Comment: The error that happens should tell you exactly why `Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined` you could have easily seen that and even searched for what that means. This question shows no research effort.

Comment: @Tareq I'm currently reading speakingjs online. It's a good book but not always as clear as I wish. If you have better resource on the subject in javascript please provide me.

Comment: @admdev there is some interactive tutorials. take a look here https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/interactive-javascript-tutorials/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var t` declares a variable. It (`t`) exists but it has the `undefined` value. When you read it, you get the `undefined` value (which `x()` returns because there is no `return` statement in that function).

`y` isn't declared anywhere. When you try to read it, you get a *ReferenceError*. (This aborts further processing so the result of the script doesn't run and the `console.log(t)` statement is never reached).

Comment: It didn't say that in IE, it only said y is undefined which is why I was confused. However in Chrome it was clearer and reported a ReferenceError like you said.

Comment: It says that in my copy of IE: https://i.imgur.com/lmYkxLy.png

Comment: I only get the SCRIPT5009 line.

Comment: @admdev — Are you using an old version of IE that no longer gets security updates from Microsoft?

Comment: I'm using 11.125.16299.0